# suggest to improve visibilty of the resources page

Tags: discussion, feature-request

### observation:

- Thanks to community effort, there is a page about [resources learning Chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/37303/resources-for-learning-chemistry).  Some moments ago it was possible to answer a question related to chemical nomenclature ([link](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/174767/what-is-the-correct-iupac-nomenclature-for-this-compound/)) with copy-pastes from this compiled "directories".
- On occasion, I find questions related to LaTeX already discussed on reddit's [r/LaTeX](https://www.reddit.com/r/LaTeX/), the moderators have a small box on the side with a couple of recommended references to consult (apparently optional, because other subreddits do not offer this):

  [image]

### question / suggestion:

By extension of the implementation on reddit, could a link to the resources page be added to a prominent spot of the layout of chemistry.se?  The panel of questions, tags, users possibly could be one option.

[image]

Comment: Well. That's nothing we can change ourselves. We would need to get staff to review this. Maybe something like this already exists on the main meta.

Comment: We could add a link from the top message in the [help center](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help), which was created by @Karsten.